# V.net.connect result causing "not responding" error

Tags: qgis, shapefile, grass-gis, error

I have a point shapefile layer (744 points) that I want to connect to a line shapefile layer (42 lines) using v.net.connect from GRASS 7. The process gives me the desired output, even if in wrong CRS (User:100000 instead of the CRS of the input layers) and as separate segments (1200+) instead of 42 single multi-line features as desired. 
The main problem is that every operation I try to do with the newly created layer causes the software to go on "not responding" mode and eventually crash.

I tried multiple actions such as changing CRS, performing singlepart to multipart, adding a virtual field or even just opening the attribute table, but each of these operations causes the software to crash. (All other layers are still working perfectly fine).

Has anybody else experienced that or has any idea on what may be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.18.17

Comment: Does the SHAPE file have a proper .prj file?

Comment: Both the initial shapefiles and the output shapefile have .prj files. I actually managed to solve the problem by creating a new project importing just the final output shapefile and not the previous shapefiles and it seems to work. Still don't understand what the problem was but at least I can work on the result now.